# Soething went wrong in my kotlin code...Someone can check my code?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have written code for sending and receiving offline SMS using GSM. My sending code is working perfectly but my receiving code is showing an error.
Please, someone, check my code and help me identify what I did wrong in my code.

I have tried everything to make my code making enable to receive and show a toast message.

1.MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity :AppCompatActivity(){

    private val requestReceiveSms: Int = 3
    private val requestSendSms: Int = 2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        snd_sms.setOnClickListener {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),
                     requestSendSms)
            }
            else{
                SendSms()
            }
        }

        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS),
                requestReceiveSms)
        }

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        if(requestCode == requestSendSms)SendSms()
    }


    private fun SendSms() {

       val number = getString(R.string.phone_number)
        val text = UserMessage.text.toString()

        SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number,null,text,null,null)

        Toast.makeText(this,"SMS Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

2.SmsReceiver Class:

```
class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {

        val extras = intent.extras

        try {
            if(extras != null){

                var sms: Array<Any> = extras.getString("pdus") as Array<Any>

                for(i in sms.indices){
                    val format = extras.getString("format")

                    var smsMessage = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                        SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray,format)
                    }else{
                        SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray)
                    }

                    var phoneNumber = smsMessage.originatingAddress
                    val messageText = smsMessage.messageBody.toString()

                    Toast.makeText(context,"$phoneNumber:(Private)\n" + "messageText: $messageText",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }catch (ex:Exception){
            //your error handling code here
            //here, consider adding Log.e("SmsReceiver", ex.localizedMessage)
            //this log statement simply prints errors to your android studio terminal and will help with debugging, alternatively leave it out

            if (context != null){
                Toast.makeText(context!!,ex.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual result:** Kotlin typecast Exception : null can not be cast to non-null type kolin.Array

**Expected result:** Toast message("phone number: private along with message")

Comment: I thin in place of `getString` should had to `getStringArray` like `var sms: Array<Any> = extras.getStringArray("pdus") as Array<Any>`

Comment: Share the code where you exactly passing the data using key `pdus`

Comment: Above1,2 .this is all the code I have write...

Comment: @KrishnaSharma I have tried getStringArray..But it showing "null can not be cast to non-null kotlin.Array<*>"

Comment: My problem  is sort out now... But there is a problem...Why Toast message is shown first and then sms recieved later...??

Comment: My new code is in the answer section below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extras.getString("pdus")` is returning `null` and you're telling it to be `Array<Any>` which it can't (as it's null)

You need to figure out why `extras.getString("pdus")` is returning you `null`

Have you passed it in properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here :class SmsReceiverplz: BroadcastReceiver() {
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
       val TAG = SmsReceiverplz::class.java.simpleName
        val pdu_type = "pdus"
        // Get the SMS message.
        val bundle = intent.extras
        var msgs: Array1<SmsMessage?>
        var strMessage = ""
        val format = bundle!!.getString("format")
        // Retrieve the SMS message received.
        val pdus = bundle.get(pdu_type) as Array1<*>?
        if (pdus != null) {
            // Check the Android version.
            val isVersionM = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            // Fill the msgs array.


           // msgs = arrayOfNulls1<SmsMessage>(pdus.size)

            msgs  = arrayOfNulls1<SmsMessage>(size = pdus.size)
            for (i in msgs.indices) {
                // Check Android version and use appropriate createFromPdu.
                if (isVersionM) {
                    // If Android version M or newer:
                    msgs[i] = createFromPdu(pdus[i] as ByteArray, format)
                } else {
                    // If Android version L or older:
                    msgs[i] = createFromPdu(pdus[i] as ByteArray)
                }
                // Build the message to show.
                strMessage += "SMS from " + msgs[i]!!.getOriginatingAddress()
                strMessage += " :" + msgs[i]!!.getMessageBody() + "\n"
                // Log and display the SMS message.
                //Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: $strMessage")
                Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This works perfectly...But there is a problem...This show Toast message before the sms received..Can someone tell me why is it happening..???